# How to compare exponential complexities?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, exponential

I have an algorithm that runs in `O(√x)`, where `x` is my input.

Now, instead of using `x`, I would like to use the number of bits of `x`, i.e. `n`. I know that `x = O(2ⁿ)`, therefore my algorithm should be `O(√x) = O(2n/2)`. Is it right?

What I cannot understand is that, as far as I know, `O(2n/2)` is equivalent to `O(2ⁿ)` (in other words: `2n` and `2n/2` grow at the same rate). But this can't be right, because it would imply that `O(√x)` is equivalent `O(x)`, which is false (`x` and `√x` don't grow at the same rate).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption, that `O(2n)` and `O(2n/2)` are equal, is wrong.

```
limn → ∞ 2n/2n/2 = limn → ∞ 2n/sqrt(2)n = limn → ∞ (2/sqrt(2))n = ∞
```

Therefore `2n/2` is in `o(2n)` (little-o).

In general: Let `a,b ∈ ℝ`.

```
                               = ∞   ∀ a > b   ⇒   aⁿ ∈ ω(bⁿ)
limn → ∞ an/bn = limn → ∞ (a/b)n = 1   ∀ a = b   ⇒   aⁿ ∈ Θ(bⁿ)
                               = 0   ∀ a < b   ⇒   aⁿ ∈ o(bⁿ)
```

Answer (score 1):

`O(2n/2)` is *not* equivalent to `O(2n)` !

As far as the O notation is concerned, different bases are not equivalent when talking about exponential behaviour.

Comment: So O(3^n) is not equivalent to O(2^n)? I was told so by my CS teacher.

Comment: Their complexity class is the same. But no, O(3^n) is not the same as O(2^n). See the answer by AbcAeffchen for the proof! (Edit: complexity class is for a problem, not for a particular algorithm.)